# Fix line height of special keyword lines (set face for logbook sum)

Tags: faces

I would like to make the lines with special keywords less disturbing, so I reduced the height of org-special-keyword. But the lines have a lot of space. This is not the case for the source-lines, where everything arranges neatly (see image below). The culprit is apparently the sum of logbook entries.

Is there a way to lower height of this part without affecting regular content, too?

[image]

Comment: What face is being used by the characters causing the excessive line height? `C-u C-x =` will tell you, and then you can adjust it.

Comment: Actually, this might be `org-clock-overlay`

Comment: Thank you for the idea! It had unfortunately no effect on the font when I set org-clock-overlay to the same font size as org-special-keyword.